# How to detect if PHP was compiled with specific option

Tags: php, shared-memory

The documentation states it clearly:

> [To use shmop you will need to compile PHP with the --enable-shmop parameter in your configure line.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/shmop.installation.php)

1. How to check if PHP is compiled with a specific option(**--enable-shmop** :D) from a script?
2. How to detect any compile time options from PHP script?

Please do not suggest using any `exec()` type functions, due to unavailability in most cases.

Comment: `phpinfo()`? If you need it on the fly, in a script, I'm not sure, sorry

Comment: @James is the entry titled Shared Memory ?
I am asking this cuz of the lack of info in google (pages 1,2,3) and found it interesting that we have functions to list all installed modules, but not possibly available

Comment: it'll show the "Configure Command", and then show or not show `--enable-shmop`

Comment: @James Could you form your last comment in a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a script on your server with the PHP function `phpinfo()` will show various info relating to your PHP configuration, including (relevant in this case) *PHP compilation options/extensions*.
(As well as various other useful info on: environment, OS, paths, headers, EGPCS, etc).

So `phpinfo()` will show you the "Configure Command" ran when PHP was compiled and anything included, so `--enable-shmop` will either be there if ran at compile time, or not be there if it wasn't.